# Connected App for Api integration with Service Provider. Need advice from ISV specialists

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, isv

I'm new to ISV development, so need some advice regarding the development process with the Connected App and Managed Package.

I have Service Provider which integrates with Salesforce, I'm using Connected App with OAuth, my question is regarding development flow.

**Question**
How do you share Managed App across different development orgs?

1. Do you create Connected App on Packaging Org, add the latest development changes to package and then install this package in development org?
2. Or there is some other approach for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one Connected App for production or Developer Edition organizations, and another one for sandboxes.

You don't have to package the Connected App inside the package.